# Does deleting data from a database affect the cursor storing the data?

Tags: android, database, cursor

I have to move some files from database A to database B.

So, I query the data into cursor from database A, then delete the data in the database A.

After that, I use cursor to insert the the data rows to database B. Are there any problems in this procedure?

Because someone told me that cursor may be only a reference, not really store the data in the cursor object. So, if I delete the database A before I insert the data into database B, there may have something abnormal!

Is there anyone who knows whether cursor is a reference to database or it really saves the data in the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case will not work. Cursor is a reference to a part of memory. If you deletes the database the data in this part of memory will be also deleted.

You can use cursor but you should delete your old database only after migration. Why do you want to delete old database before inserting results in a new database?

Answer (score 0):

A `Cursor` can act only as a **reference** and if you delete your data from the database A before inserting into database B, you would completely lose your data.

A better and more logical approach would be to query the data from database A, insert it into database B and then delete the data from the database A.